# Docker CLI ERROR: "my_wordpress_wordpress_1 Cannot start service wordpress: driver failed"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

It is the first time that I tried to install Wordpress in a container, I have used the following from the official docker documentation, but I received the following errors:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

Error:

```
Creating my_wordpress_db_1 ... done
Creating my_wordpress_wordpress_1 ...
Creating my_wordpress_wordpress_1 ... error

ERROR: for my_wordpress_wordpress_1  Cannot start service wordpress: driver failed programming external connec                                                                                            tivity on endpoint my_wordpress_wordpress_1 (eaa2b38842baac2cbc2126426076f542fd8806509d5d5b19160e07a38f89f173)                                                                                            : Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpo                                                                                            int my_wordpress_wordpress_1 (eaa2b38842baac2cbc2126426076f542fd8806509d5d5b19160e07a38f89f173): Bind for 0.0.                                                                                            0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have pasted contains a lot of blank spaces which makes the output hard to read. But if you dig through the reason, Docker states the following why your Wordpress image will not work.

```
ERROR: for wordpress Cannot start service wordpress: 
driver failed programming external connectivity on 
endpoint my_wordpress_wordpress_1 (eaa2b38842baac2cbc2126426076f542fd8806509d5d5b19160e07a38f89f173): 
Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated
```

The solution is to figure out which other resource is allocating port `8000` and close that program. It might be some other docker instance running, try `docker ps -a` to view all docker images. Alternatively you may specify a different port in your `docker-compose.yml`-file.

You can try

```
ports:
  - "8080:80"
```

In your example you have `8000:80`

Answer (score 0):

You made a change to compiled information after running:
`npm run build:dev`

In my case I had manually modified **/etc/hosts** after compiling the build.
This broke referenced paths in the build.

Re-running `npm run build:dev` fixes the issue.